# Symfony 4 Dotenv escape special characters

Tags: symfony, escaping, symfony4, dotenv

I use a password with a special char and symfony return an error "Malformed parameter "url"."

How can i use this kind of password ? `foo?bar`

I try with variables like that

```
DATABASE_USER='foo'
DATABASE_PASSWORD='foo?bar'
DATABASE_URL=mysql://${DATABASE_USER}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@100.100.100.100:3306/db
```

But is not working

Comment: has to be url encoded. so `%3F` for `?`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

as the variable name suggests, the `DATABASE_URL` has to be a URL. that is, everything that is a character with meaning in URLs (for example `#`, `?`, `:`, ...) has to be URL-encoded.

For example `?` has to be encoded as `%3F` if it is supposed to appear in a different meaning than to mark the query. There are lots of tools online to URL-encode stuff...

Answer (score 11):

Use password urlencoded through `urlencode()` or online:

(e.g: ZZ?*?daWm  => ZZ%3F%2A%3FdaWm

Full database url param should like:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://test_user:ZZ%3F%2A%3FdaWm@127.0.0.1:3306/test_db
```

And then go to `./app/config/packages/doctrine.yaml`

I had url parameter with resolve prefix:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # (....)
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Simply remove the prefix 'resolve'  which fixed the problem,
After changes:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # (....)
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Comment: It appears that the Symfony resolve function will try to replace %foo% with a variable defined in the YAML. That's why it fails in our case. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html#built-in-environment-variable-processors